# проверка на наличие строки в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа должна работать следующим образом:
return True, если каждый элемент в массиве является целым числом или числом с плавающей запятой без десятичных знаков.
return True, если массив пуст.
return False для всех остальных входных данных.

Почему мой код заканчивается на 5 строке, в списке [1, 2, 3, 4] нет строк или None?

```
  def is_int_array(arr):
    if arr == []:
        return True
    else:
        if str or None in arr:
            return False
        else:
            a = sum(arr)
            if type(a) == int:

                return (True)
            elif type(a) == float:
                return a.is_integer()


print(is_int_array([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверка типа делается не так.

Вам каждый элемент нужно проверить в массиве, например так:

```
if any([isinstance(elem, str) or elem is None for elem in arr]):
    return False
```

Как это работает? Функция isinstance проверяет, что элемент elem является экземпляром одного из классов переданных вторым аргумент, а именно str или None и если да, возращает True, в итоге мы получаем список булевых значений True/False и если какой-то из них будет True, то функция any вернет значение True и мы вернем False.

Comment: В таком случае появляется ошибка       TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Comment: Я поправил.....